# Can't toggle offline mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

I've just installed AS 4.0 alpha 4 and imported setting from AS 3.5.2 where I had offline mode ON.

Settings on AS 4.0 are different and I can't find that option. Now I'm stuck on offline mode and can't build a project. All I get is

`No cached version listing for xxx available for offline mode.`

Where did this setting go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "Find Action" shortcut to find what you are looking for.

- **Windows**: "Control + Shift + A"
- **Mac**: "Cmd + Shift + A"

Once the *Find Action* popup is present start typing "*toggle offline mode*". It should show up shortly, and you can even toggle it from there.

[image: Find Action row]

Check out the whole list of keyboard shortcuts at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts).

**UPDATE**

You can check the release notes [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features?utm_source=android-studio-4-0&utm_medium=studio-assistant-preview#gradle-offline-ui)

> To enable or disable Gradle's offline mode, first select View > Tool Windows > Gradle from the menu bar. Then, near the top of the Gradle window, click Toggle Offline Mode Gradle offline button in the Gradle panel..

Comment: I've verified and it's there.

Comment: Toggle through the gradle tool windows works, thanks.
But the option seems to have been removed from the Find Action

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Giorgos Neokleous a lot[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txbsU.jpg)